# In AutoCompleteTextView apply on item click listner returns always id as a 1

Tags: android, json, android-volley, autocompletetextview

**This is my json responce :-**

```
{
  "ReplyCode": 1,
  "Message": "Franchisee and Plans List",
"data2": [
    {
      "StateId": 1,
      "StateName": "Andaman and Nicobar Island",
      "CountryId": 1
    },
    {
      "StateId": 2,
      "StateName": "Andhra Pradesh",
      "CountryId": 1
    },
    {
      "StateId": 3,
      "StateName": "Arunachal Pradesh",
      "CountryId": 1
    },
    {
      "StateId": 4,
      "StateName": "Assam",
      "CountryId": 1
    },
```

**This is my method by which i am fetching data from the json :-**

```
 public void volleyStatedata() {

        if (mGeneralUtilities.isConnected()) {
            mProgressDialog.show();
            StringRequest stateRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, GlobalData.REGISTER_DATA_URL,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {


                            mProgressDialog.dismiss();

                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data2");
                                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                    PojoState pojoState = new PojoState();
                                    JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                    String stateId = jsonObject1.getString("StateId");
                                    String stateName = jsonObject1.getString("StateName");
                                    mStateList.add(stateName);
                                    mStateIdList.add(stateId);
                                    pojoState.setmStateId(stateId);
                                    pojoState.setmStatename(stateName);
                                    mpojoStateList.add(pojoState);


                                }


                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

                            Log.e("error", "" + volleyError.getMessage());


                        }
                    }) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();


                    return params;
                }
            };

            RequestQueue stateQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());

            stateQueue.add(stateRequest);
        } else {

            mGeneralUtilities.showAlertDialog("Hey User !", "Please connect to the internet", "Ok");

        }
    }
```

**This is my Adapter where i am setting it to the autocompletetextview :-**

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mStateList);
        mActState.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mActState.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                mpojoStateList.get(i).getmStateId();


            }
        });
```

My problem is autocompletetextview always return id 1.i am applying onitemclick listner on it.but it is getting id 1 always.i want to id accordingly to the state as per shown my json.Can anyone tell me how can I achieve this ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code uses `i` that returns in the `onItemClick` callback, which refers to the item you clicked from the visible items in the auto-complete list, not your original list. When you click on the first item in the auto-complete list, `i=0`, which means it always returns the "*Andaman and Nicobar Island*" item whose `StateId=1`.

Off the top of my head, you can get the item String from the `mAdapter` and compare it to your `mpojoStateList` and find the corresponding item. (Check the sample code)

```
    final ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mStateList);
    mActState.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mActState.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            String itemName = mAdapter.getItem(i);

            for (PojoState pojo : mpojoStateList) {
                if (pojo.mStateName.equals(itemName)) {
                    String id = pojo.getmStateId(); // This is the correct ID
                    break; // No need to keep looping once you found it.
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

It also is better if, inside your `PojoState` object, you override your `toString()` method and make it return the `mStateName`, and pass the `mpojoStateList` to the adapter without having to make 3 `ArrayLists`. That way, `mAdapter.getItem(i)` will return a `PojoState` object instead of a String, and you can use its ID without referring to the returned position (`i`).